# Python Store chained methods

Tags: python, selenium, oop, inheritance

We do have defined tests for apium/selenium like this:

```
def click_start(self):
    self.log.logEvent("Click on start")
    return IntroPage1(self.log, self.device)

def click_skip(self):
    self.log.logEvent("Click skip")
    return Overview(self.log, self.device)
etc..
```

We now have defined following test flow:

```
page.click_start().click_skip().clickPlus().click_HyperCar().click_Continue().editTireAmount(4).editCarName("Koenigsegg")
```

Above technique gives us autocompletion.

We need to store this method chain as a shorthand in order to re-use the test at other places. Is there a more elegant way than to do:

```
reUseTest = eval("page.click_start().click_skip().clickPlus().click_SportsCar().click_Continue().editGoalAmount("60000").editGoalName("Moderate")")
```

Comment: why not define a function?

Comment: Are you sure that your last line is working? It has problems with quotes usage and also I think `exec()` should be used instead of `eval()`

Comment: @appleapple can you give an example? @ Andersson The example is from my noob colleague haha, obviously he did not try it yet, sorry for that.

Comment: @nottinhill , what do you mean by *"more elegant way"*? What you expect to be a good answer to your question?

Comment: I think we are going to roll with exec. With more elegant, I mean sth that does not involve encoding code into strings.

Comment: `page.click_start().click_skip().clickPlus()` this code is working or it's just a sequence of methods that should be called one by one as `page.click_start() page.click_skip() page.clickPlus()`?

Comment: Create a method called `add_car()` (or whatever) and take in two parameters, `number_of_tires` and `car_name`, and pass those two parameters to `.editTireAmount()` and `.editCarName()`. The method would be your one-liner test flow you've defined in your question.

Comment: I would suggest you read up on page object model. It will help you better organize your methods into classes based on pages your script touches. You can still group multiple actions together, like `add_car()`, that cross page objects but it will help in maintenance and organization.